# Django - Rendering a template multiple times in a loop

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates, local-storage

I have a Django view that receives a list of selected files in request.

I want to iterate over all files and render the same template for each file (one after the other).

**Is there a way/hack to re-render the template with the modified context without returning from the view?**

**Or is there a way to do that with javascript using local-storage, i.e., calling the view for each file (one after the other)?**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making the differnt parameter.. Send those parameter after checking the condition and make sure that the dictationay have same keys.